# UnsatisfiedLinkError with stitching module in javacv android project

Tags: android, javacv

after few days of digging, testing and getting frustrated I decided it's time to ask the question.

Error is generated by createDefault method. I get error log as attached below. But structure of my catalog looks fine (i think).

catalogs:

gen libs obj res src .classpath .project AndroidManifest.xml ic_launcher-web.png proguard-project.txt project.properties .settings assets bin Debug

/libs: javacpp.jar javacv.jar armeabi android-support-v4.jar

/libs/armeabi: libjniavfilter.so libjniavformat.so libjniavutil.so libjnicvkernels.so libjniopencv_calib3d.so libjniopencv_contrib.so libjniopencv_core.so libjniopencv_features2d.so libjniopencv_flann.so libjniopencv_highgui.so libjniopencv_imgproc.so libjniopencv_legacy.so libjniopencv_ml.so libjniopencv_nonfree.so libjniopencv_objdetect.so libjniopencv_photo.so libjniopencv_stitching.so libjniopencv_video.so libjniopencv_videostab.so libjnipostproc.so libjniswresample.so libjniswscale.so libopencv_calib3d.so libopencv_contrib.so libopencv_core.so libopencv_features2d.so libopencv_flann.so libopencv_gpu.so libopencv_highgui.so libopencv_imgproc.so libopencv_info.so libopencv_legacy.so libopencv_ml.so libopencv_nonfree.so libopencv_objdetect.so libopencv_photo.so libopencv_stitching.so libopencv_video.so libopencv_videostab.so libtbb.so libjniARToolKitPlus.so libjniavcodec.so libjniavdevice.so

error log:

04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.example.myapp.Opencvpart.generatePanorama(Opencvpart.java:133) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.example.myapp.Opencvpart.onOptionsItemSelected(Opencvpart.java:118) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:962) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:514) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:99) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_stitching$Stitcher.(opencv_stitching.java:1165) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): ... 20 more 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]: 149 could not load needed library 'libopencv_stitching.so' for 'libjniopencv_stitching.so' (find_library[1201]: 149 'libopencv_stitching.so' failed to load previously) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_stitching.(opencv_stitching.java:92) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): ... 25 more 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]: 149 could not load needed library '../../lib/libopencv_gpu.so' for 'libopencv_stitching.so' (load_library[1093]: Library '../../lib/libopencv_gpu.so' not found) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:577) 04-17 22:33:16.001: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): ... 27 more

What should i change to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You be get help from [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-how-to-handle-exception-initializer-error/)

But i am not sure that you are solve your problem. But i expect you are get idea how to solve this problem.

Best of luck!